# Read big files and chunk upload with Dropbox Api in c#

Tags: c#, api, dropbox, chunking

i have big sql backups and i want to keep them in dropbox, but i just want to send a copy to dropbox and move the file to an external hard disc because of my server hard disc space.

I'm trying to use chunk upload of dropbox api, and here is the sample code they give.

```
private async Task ChunkUpload(DropboxClient client, string folder, string fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chunk upload file...");
        // Chunk size is 128KB.
        const int chunkSize = 128 * 1024;

        // Create a random file of 1MB in size.
        var fileContent = new byte[1024 * 1024];        
        new Random().NextBytes(fileContent);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(fileContent))
        {
            int numChunks = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)stream.Length / chunkSize);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
            string sessionId = null;

            for (var idx = 0; idx < numChunks; idx++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start uploading chunk {0}", idx);
                var byteRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);

                using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, byteRead))
                {
                    if (idx == 0)
                    {
                        var result = await client.Files.UploadSessionStartAsync(memStream);
                        sessionId = result.SessionId;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        UploadSessionCursor cursor = new UploadSessionCursor(sessionId, (ulong)(chunkSize * idx));

                        if (idx == numChunks - 1)
                        {
                            await client.Files.UploadSessionFinishAsync(cursor, new CommitInfo(folder + "/" + fileName), memStream);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            await client.Files.UploadSessionAppendAsync(cursor, memStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have file paths, i want to chunk upload my big files, but just couldn't manage to get this sample code to work with sending path of file. My modifications for chunk read did not work, i'm googling for 2 weeks. Finally i wanted to ask about this.

How can i make this method, to work with sending file path, and make a chunk upload from that big file ?

Thanks from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is using random bytes.

Comment the codes for the `random` stream and include in the `using` statement your file stream.  Include the full path with filename and extension in `localContentFullPath` and separate the `filename` for the file list display in DropBox.

```
    public async Task ChunkUpload(DropboxClient client, string folder, string localContentFullPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chunk upload file...");
        // Chunk size is 128KB.
        const int chunkSize = 128 * 1024;

        // Create a random file of 1MB in size.
        // var fileContent = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        // new Random().NextBytes(fileContent);

        //using (var stream = new MemoryStream(fileContent))

        var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(localContentFullPath.ToString());
        using (var stream = new FileStream(localContentFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
...
```

Comment: @Marlo, can you please tell me what I can use after using and is folder specifies dropbox folder name .   this is my code..     using (var stream = new FileStream(content, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync("/" + folder + "/" + file, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: stream);
                }

Comment: It is really slow, more than 2 times when we compare it with browser uploading. Is there any way to optimise it.